# Получить массив из JS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Вечер добрый!
Отправляю массив с данными через AJAX

```
                $('form').submit(function(event) {
                    // event.preventDefault();

                    var formData = {
                        'id': id,
                        'userID' : <?php echo $myId; ?>,
                        'comment' : $('textarea#comment_text').val()

                    };
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '../php/process_Comment.php',
                        data: formData,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        encode: true,
                        success: function(res){
                            console.log(res);

                        },
                        error: function() {
                            alert("Error!");
                        }
                    })
                })
```

Теперь мне нужно как-то работать с переданным массивом в php. 
Пытался просто `$_POST['id']`  , но это не подходит.

```
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    echo $idPic = $_POST['id'];
    $idUser = $_POST['userID'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `comments`(`id_picture`, `text`, `id_user`, `data_add`) VALUES ($idPic, '$comment' , $idUser, now())";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
}
```

Comment: "но это не подходит" - всему миру подходит, а Вам не подходит? `$_POST['id']`, `$_POST['userID']`, `$_POST['comment']`

Comment: нет.  Показывает как Array()

Comment: что показывает "как Array()"? Зачем Вы разговариваете обрывками фраз? Это Вам нужна моя помощь, или мне - Ваша?

Comment: извините. Я проверяю эти переменные через isset($_POST['id']) и их просто не существует.

Comment: `console.log(formaData);` - что в консоли браузера?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: formaData is not defined. Но это же ассоциативный массив, разве что-то не так?

Comment: Вставьте строчку `console.log(formData);` перед `$.ajax({`. Подозреваю, что переменная `id` не назначена.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: formaData is not defined. Переменная id назначена, я могу её вывести в консоль.

Comment: Пардон, `formData`, конечно.

Comment: Что-то я вообще въехать не могу... var formData = {...} - объявление ассоциативного массива.

Comment: у меня в "console.log(form**A**Data);" была опечатка, нужно `console.log(formData);`

Comment: Аааа, всё, понял. Да, в консоль выводятся данные из массива. С ним всё хорошо.

Comment: Добавьте то, что выводится в консоль, в вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oткомментируйте

```
// event.preventDefault();
```

или возвращайте `false` из обработчика `submit`. У Вас происходит стандартный сабмит формы, в которой нет поля c `name="id"`.

И кавычки не нужны:

```
var formData = {
  id: id,
  userID: <?php echo $myId; ?>,
  comment: $('textarea#comment_text').val()
};
```

Comment: Всё заработало. Спасибо Вам огромное!

Comment: @TomWest На здоровье. Успехов!

Comment: благодарю, и вам того же С:

Answer (score 0):

Brother, Все просто.

```
<script>
  var data = new FormData();
  data.append('id' , id);
data.append('userID' , ключ твоего юзер айди.);
data.append('comment' , $('textarea#comment_text').val());
$.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '../php/process_Comment.php',
                    data: data,
                    dataType: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    encode: true, // желательно удалить эту строку, я не помню что она делает
                    success: function(res){
                        console.log(res);

                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert("Error!");
                    }
                })
--------
'userID' : <?php echo $myId; ?>, 
// Что за странная строчка кода. Первый раз такой способ отправки вижу. Хоть работает?)
// Почему бы в самом php не получать эту переменную?
</script>
```